# How to Drag only one item per container in ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ng2-dragula

I generate different containers automatically from arrays, this is my app-component.ts:

```
columnItems = [
        {
            name: 'Name',
        },
        {
            name: 'User'
        },
        {
            name: 'Email'
        }
    ];
```

An the second Array:

```
column = [
        {
            name: 'One Column',
        },
        {
            name: 'Two Column'
        },
        {
            name: 'Three Column'
        },
        {
            name: 'Four Column'
        }
    ];
```

on my app-component.html I have this code

```
<div class="wrapper_mapping">
                    <div class="container_mapping system_column" [dragula]="'mapping-columns'">
                        <h5 class="no-drag">System Columns</h5>
                        <div *ngFor="let columnItem of columnItems">{{ columnItem.name }}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container_mapping" [dragula]="'mapping-columns'" *ngFor="let c of column">
                        <h5 class="no-drag" style="display: block;"> {{ c.name }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

These generate a 5 columns with the columnsItem on the left and 4 columns to the right, I want to allow drag and drog elements from the left column to each on the right, I use a  html tag to create headers and the class "no-drag" makes the header no draggable, two questions:

- How could I make the header  element fixed, I mean prevent drop elements up the header, I would like to drop elements only above the header?
- Also I want to drop only one element for each container on the right, every container on the right should only have one element, restrict drop more than one into it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I'm facing the same.

Comment: I think you need to simplify your question to get an answer